# Making parts of a 3D model move with attached element

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I am new to blender having made the change from 3D StudioMax.

I trying to find a solution for what appears to be a relatively simple problem.The left hand part of the model is fixed, the top bar is attached to the left fixed side and the right moveable side, by a horizontal bar.

I want to rotate the horizontal bar at the left blue pivot point by 90 degrees (upward toward the fixed left side) and have the right hand side rotate at the right horizontal blue pivot point.

[image: Foldable side barrier]

I have tried rigging and can not get any usable results.

Comment: You say that you've tried rigging, but not **how** you've tried. I suggest you share your Blend file so that we can have a look as a single image doesnt' tell us much.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/315471/edit) your question here and paste the link into it.